# Property assignments too slow in execution

Tags: c#, wpf

These assignments

```
dtSubBefore2 = DateTime.Now;
if (entryAfterNode != null)
   //if (entryBefore.targetNode.Path_SetAttributes == entryAfterNode.Path_1_Original)
{
    entryAfterNode.task7 = enTasks.SetAttributes;
    entryAfterNode.Path_SetAttributes = entryBefore.targetNode.Path_SetAttributes;
    entryAfterNode.Path_SetCopyOrAttributesSource = entryBefore.targetNode.Path_SetCopyOrAttributesSource;
    entryAfterNode.Path_SetAttributesSourceBase = entryBefore.targetNode.Path_SetAttributesSourceBase;
    entryAfterNode.Path_SetAttributesBase = entryBefore.targetNode.Path_SetAttributesBase;
    entryAfterNode.SetFileAttributes = entryBefore.targetNode.SetFileAttributes;

    // SetAttributes can set bActivated!! (because not inheritted from BeforeView)
    entryAfterNode.bActivated = entryBefore.targetNode.bActivated;
}
dtSubAfter2 = DateTime.Now;
```

take about 5-10ms, which is to slow for me.
The Properties are visualized in a complex way and I´m looping through this code up to 100k times.
Is there a way to deactivate the visualization of the properties till after the loop is done, and then update the properties visualization to make it faster?

Or do I have to make extra properties without `OnPropertyChanged`?

Can I still update everything with `UpdateLayout` then?

Comment: We have no idea what either the setters involved or the getters do, so we can't tell what's taking a long time. We don't know whether other things are triggered when the setters are called, etc. A short but complete program demonstrating the problem would go a long way here...

Comment: how is the entryBefore.targetNode implemented? could that be the bottleneck? if you try `var target = entryBefore.targetNode;` and then use that target during the setting, does that help?